# Navbar is getting fit properly on the page react js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

this is my code on bootstrap for navbar but it is not getting fit proper as u can see in png
it is coming at the center of the page i want it to cover the whole page .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uid12.png)

Brand

```
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between" id="navbarCollapse">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link active">Home</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Profile</a>
                <div class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Messages</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Inbox</a>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Sent</a>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Drafts</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <form class="form-inline">
                <div class="input-group">                    
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Login</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Can you share complete code?

Comment: You need to share a complete HTML document because this is not coming from the navbar itself but from the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.

In the example below I use container-fluid with a margin of 0 and padding of 0.
(You can do it without container-fluid wrapping your navbar, it is your choice for the sake of an example I will leave it in the snippet.)

Then if you want to put content inside of the navbar inside of the container. You can put div with a class of a container after starting the nav tag.

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      background: #121212;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid m-0 p-0">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>
```